# Python Classes and Objects Attribute error : object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am new to python and while learning OOP in python i am getting errors like

```
AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute 'sound'
```

for below code

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name  = name
        self.age  = age

    def description(self):
        return print(f"name is {self.name} and age is {self.age}")

    def speak(self, sound):
        return print(f"{self.name} says {self.sound}")

tommy = Dog("tommy",10)
tommy.description()
tommy.speak("bow-bow")
```

Now my other doubt is related to inheritance where i am getting error like:

```
AttributeError: 'Bulldog' object has no attribute 'speed'
```

for below code :

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name  = name
        self.age  = age

    def description(self):
        return print(f"name is {self.name} and age is {self.age}")


class Bulldog(Dog):
    def run(self, speed):
        return print(f"The speed of dog is {self.speed}")

tommy = Bulldog("tommy",10)
tommy.description()
tommy.run(5)
```

Comment: `sound` isn't an attribute; it's an argument (i.e., a local variable) of the `speak` method. Likewise, `speed` is a local variable of `run`, not an attribute.

Comment: What is what you don't understand about "'Dog' object has no attribute 'sound'"?

Comment: Both problems are the same. The second problem has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: ok @chepner  then how to call ```speak``` method by ```tommy``` instance?

Comment: @vsb: You already know how to call  `tommy.speak()`. You did it in the first part of the question. What you should think about is how `Bulldog` class should differ from the `Dog` class. What is the purpose? The `run()` method implementation is actually not the good reason to introduce the `Bulldog` class -- unless the Bulldog adds the `self.speed` attribute. The `run` tries to use that attribute, but its value was never set (the variabl does not exist). The `speed` is not the `self.speed`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to remove the self. when trying to return the print as these are passed through as parameters and not identified in the object itself.

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def description(self):
        return print(f"name is {self.name} and age is {self.age}")


class Bulldog(Dog):
    def run(self, speed):
        return print(f"The speed of dog is {speed}")

tommy = Bulldog("tommy", 10)
tommy.description()
tommy.run(5)
```

This is the same for both speed and sound, note I also changed some formatting about how the print statement works

Comment: Why have you changed formatting? f-strings are all-way better when + str(). They better in speed, memory, and intuitivity. '+' for strings is a bad idea for any language,  that is why all of this weird StringBuilders born. Poor Shlemiel in https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: @Sav Didn't think of that sorry, I've never used f-strings before so I had no idea what they were or why It wasn't working when I copied the code for me to run, thank you though.